# voltage follower operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, cadence

I am trying to simulate a buffer with an op-amp using CMOS, I am using Cadence. The gain I am getting is low (16dB). I am trying to reach a gain of 90. how can I increase it?

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa358.pdf?&ts=1589808642619

Comment: Show your actual circuit diagram.

Comment: At what frequency? GBW is only 80MHz for that part, so your frequency has to be well under 1MHz if you want it reasonably flat.